# How to make members chat with each other on an android app

Tags: java, android, api, chat

am working on an e-commerce app, where buyers and sellers should be able to initiate conversation via an in-app chat interface and negotiate prices and setup meeting points for exchange .
Is there a Chat SDK that can make this easy for me or do i have to build a chat interface for my app from scratch and if so, what's the logic to be used.

A good example is a cryptocurrency platform like paxful.com where sellers and buyers Chat on the platform and carry out transactions or Upwork where freelancer and employer initiate chat on the platform about how the project should be carried out.

Comment: Requests for libraries are off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

[Firebase-Chat-Sdk](https://chatsdk.co/downloads/android-chat-sdk-firebase/) will be helpful for you. You can see this [Demo](https://github.com/chat21/chat21-android-demo) application using Firebase chat.
Other than this if you want to make a chat interface along with your own back end server then you need to create back end API and front end interface from your own.